# How to run a script from GEANY (win 7)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, python-requests

please help me sort this out.

I have run the following script from IDLE (win7):

```
import requests
import lxml.html

def get_doc(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as exc:
        print('A Connection error occurred. _____ ', exc)
    else:
        return req


if __name__ == "__main__":
    baseUrl = 'http://en.modagram.com/'
    #baseUrl = 'http://forum.saransk.ru/'

    req = get_doc(baseUrl)
    doc_html = req.text
    print(doc_html)
    doc_obj = lxml.html.document_fromstring(doc_html)
```

As a result, the script writes a html page.

I have run this script from the same GEANY (win7). As a result get the following [error message](http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/er.png)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "index.py", line 19, in
>   
>       print(doc_html)   File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp866.py", l
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.er UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't enco 92: character maps to

Please tell me how to successfully run the script from GEANY?

Comment: Are you sure you run it from IDLE 3.3?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to print to the screen instead of simply writing the file, but try `sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), errors='replace')`. Printing  shouldn't raise an exception after this, but unsupported characters will be printed as the replacement character (e.g. a question mark).

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, when you print `doc_html`, Python tries to convert it from the `charmap` encoding but fails.

Try this instead :

```
print(doc_html.decode('charmap'))
```

If it doesn't work (which I think will be the case), try this:

```
print(doc_html.decode('charmap', errors='ignore'))
```

Comment: in both cases get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: What does `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` show?

Comment: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=3, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)